# How to Mock RequestContextHolder in junit testing groovy and grails

Tags: grails, groovy, junit

How to mock:

```
Long countryId = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()?.session.country_id?.toLong();
Country country = Country.get(countryId)
```

in junit testing using **Groovy and Grails framework** in **STS**?

Answer (score 5):

you can set RequestAttributes in test
eg:

method to be test

```
def someMethod () {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();

    ...

    return null;
}
```

test the method

```
def testSomeMethod() {
    given:
    RequestAttributes mockRequest = new ServletWebRequest(new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/test"))
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(mockRequest)

    when:
    def result = userDetailsService.someMethod()

    then:
    ...
}
```